# Stein and Shakarchi, Complex analysis, Proposition $2.3$

Tags: complex-analysis

[page 12(Stein and Shakarchi, Complex Analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUfkz.jpg)

[page 13(Stein and Shakarchi, Complex Analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QL16r.jpg)

My question has to do with the proof for proposition $2.3$. I am wondering how he arrived at the first equation on Page $13$. Can someone explain the complete proof?

Comment: Two by two matrices of the form $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ -b & a \end{pmatrix}$ with real entries are isomorphic to the complex numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether my understanding is the true...

I think in the first question on Page 13, the left side $J_F(x_0,y_0)(H)$ is a matrix multiplication (it may be better if $H$ is written into column vector)...And the middle side is in 'complex number form'...

So I think the first '$=$' should be a kind of isomorphism...